# Google one tap sign up/sign in approval request

Tags: api, google-signin, google-identity-toolkit, google-identity

I requested one tap signup/signin for website API as documented in https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/

However, there has been no update or hear an update from them for more than a week. Does anybody know how long it usually takes to get the request reviewed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got mail back from them after around **3 weeks** of submitting the form.

They said currently you won't be granted access to API. However, they are in the process of including some additional security from their side and it may take a few months. We can hope to get API access then.

Comment: Got the same response back from them too!  It seems like there's a security issue related to the one tap signin and they won't accept further requests until this gets resolved.